# Using Arcpy or Modeler to add SPOT 6/7 Imagery to Mosaic Dataset?

Tags: arcpy, mosaic-dataset

I cannot get ArcPy to add images in subfolders.

When using ArcPy (sample code from ESRI website), I see that it finds the DIM file, but it does not import it into the mosaic dataset.

I can manually add each file one at time using the Add mosaic dataset tool, but that is extremely time consuming.

An example of my file directory would be

S:\Spot6Imagery\SPOT_6_2016\VOL_SPOT6\IMG_SPOt6_P

The scenes and dim would be located in the IMG_SPOT6_P folder.  I would like to add just the SPOT6Imagery directory and the tool import all images.

[image: Error Example]

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Without it, is too difficult identify the problem